# Rails 4.0 multiple models and one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of learning Ruby on Rails, and now I have created the mobile version of my application.

I created the relation between models ans controller is one-one. Now I want to make changes to manage three models from one controller. I have read and watch videos a lot about how to do this but, it doesn't work when I try to do it in my application.

**Models:**

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :sections

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
```

**Controller:**

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  has_mobile_fu
  layout "admin"
  before_action :confirm_logged_in

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.newest_first
    @pages   = @subjects.pages.sorted
  end
```

This is the error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `pages' for #  <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Subject:0x007fbbf3c9b218>):
>     app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:10:in`index'

The application works well if I keep each model managed by its controller. The problem started now that I want to control multiple models from one controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can definitely use multiple models in a single controller. The issue here is you're calling a method that doesnt exist for the active record relation.

An active record relation is typically a collection of returned objects from a query using active record. So the newest_first is returning multiple, not just one. If you want to get all pages for the subjects and sort them, you can do this:

```
@subjects = Subject.newest_first
@pages = @subjects.map(&:pages).flatten.sort { |a, b| a.title <=> b.title }
```

Can switch the attribute on which you wish to sort by. The map function goes through each one, and returns the object of which i passed in the symbol. It's a shortcut for:

```
@subjects.map { |subject| subject.pages }
```

The flatten then takes that array of active record relations and flattens it into a single array. I then just use the array sort.

**Edit** Here's a way you can do it using the database:

```
@subjects = Subject.newest_first
@pages = Page.where.not(:subject_id => nil).order(:title)
```

Comment: Can see my edit if you like, just realized one can clean it up further by using the database to query for pages that are only associated.

Answer (score 2):

**MVC**

Something else you'll benefit from is to look at the [MVC Programming Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

Rails is famous for its strict coherence to the `Model-View-Controller` pattern, as it works like this:

> - You send a request to your app
> - Rails "routes" your request to a specific controller / action
> - The controller will then collate data from your `Models`
> - The controller will then render a `view` to display this data

The relationship between models and controllers is exclusive; meaning you don't have to call certain models from a controller, etc.

So the basic answer is **no**, you don't need to call a single model from a controller. However, you *do* need to ensure you have the correct model associations set up, as per the explanation below:

---

**Associations**

The caveat here, is that since Ruby is [`object-orientated`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (and Rails, by virtue of being built on Ruby, also being so), it's generally considered best practice to build your application *around* objects

"Objects" are basically elaborate variables (constructed from your `Model` classes), but the *pattern* behind making OOP work properly is super important - everything from [`Rails' routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to your controller actions are designed to be `object-ORIENTATED`

[image]

Each time you initiate an instance of a `Model`, Rails is actually building an `object` for you to use. This object allows you to call / use a series of attributes / methods for the object, allowing you to create the experience you require with Rails

--

The bottom line -

I would *highly* recommend examining the `ActiveRecord Associations` in your models (which will determine whether you need to call a single `model` or not):

```
#app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb
Class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @subjects = Subject.newest_first #-> good use of OOP
      @posts = # this is where your error occurs (`.posts` is only an attribute of each `Subject` object instance, which is fixed using the accepted answer)
   end
end
```

Hopefully this gives you some more ideas about how to construct Rails applications